# how to send image in email with PHPMailer

Tags: php, image, email, phpmailer

i'm new in PHP and i want to send image which is upload by user from his/her computer in mail i'm using PHPMailer. 
Please give way with example with different file.

**file1.php**

```
  < input type="file" id="lcimage" name="image" />
```

**file2.php**

```
 $LC = $_POST['image'];
    $mail->AddEmbeddedImage($LC, 'lcimage', $LC);
    <img src="" />
```

Comment: While your question has been answered, all that you need to know to do this is very thoroughly explained in PHP and PHPMailer docs, which would be found by the most trivial search. Posting questions like this is just lazy and wastes everyone's time, including yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this..

```
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('logo.jpg', 'logoimg');
$mail->Body = "<h1>Test 1 of PHPMailer html</h1><p>This is a test picture: <img src=\"cid:logoimg\" /><img src=\"cid:logo2img\" /></p>";
```

hope this will help you

Answer (score 3):

file type elements are not added in $_POST variable.
There is a different super global available for uploaded files i.e. $_FILES

First thing, make sure you have added enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute in your form
otherwise uploaded file elements will not be received in $_FILES

```
    <form method="post" action="process.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input type="file" id="lcimage" name="image" />
    </form>
```

And for adding this file in the email you can use this code.

```
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],
                         $_FILES['image']['name']);
```